# Como ejecutar un proceso batch en Azure con PAAS (sin usar VM)?

Tags: azure, batch

¿ Como se podría ejecutar un proceso batch (*.bat) en Azure sin utilizar VM ni servidores, solo servicios PAAS o SAAS ?

Se trata de extraer un archivo tipo CSV desde un servidor SFTP visible desde Internet, llevarlo a algun storage en la Nube y luego procesarlo con un programa Java (.jar) que, en esencia, se encarga de importar los registros hacia una Base de Datos Azure SQL.  En caso extremo, podría cambiar el .jar por otro programa u otro método. Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente tienes dos opciones para ejecutar tu código en Microsoft Azure como PaaS:

1. Azure Web Jobs en Azure App Service: te permitirá ejecutar tu .bat a demanda. El servicio arranca desde un nivel gratuito, y puede escalar en cantidad de cores y memoria según tu necesidad. Más información en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs.
2. Azure functions: si lo que quieres es ir a un esquema "serverless" para ejecutar tu código. El costo se da por la cantidad de ejecuciones y por el costo computacional (medido por la cantidad de memoria utilizada durante el tiempo de ejecución). Tiene un umbral bastante alto antes de comenzar a cobrar por el servicio. Más información en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview

Comment: Gracias por los datos.  Entenderia que la primera opción es la que me interesaría porque con la segunda posiblemente no podría ejecutar el proceso java (*.jar).   Estuve revisando y aun tengo dudas. Conoces algún link o un ejemplo de cargar un archivo .bat y ejecutarlo ?  No hay mucha información realmente.

Comment: Los pasos para subir el código y ejecutarlo a petición se encuentran en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateOnDemand

Comment: Para poder ejecutar el .jar puedes crear un archivo .bat que contenga lo siguiente:  

`set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin`  

`java -jar nombrearchivo.jar`

Comment: Muchas gracias !. Lo probaré